# Logical operators with three lists

Tags: python

I have a problem with lists:
I have three lists:

```
Pipe_sizes = [15,15,22,15,32,45]
Flow_rates = [0.1,0.3,1,2,0.4,1.5]
Material_pipes = [Copper, Copper, PVC, Steel, Steel, Copper]
```

I would like to use logical operators to change the list Pipe_sizes as below:

```
If the material is Copper, I will use the follow logical operators:
if Flow_rates <= 0.2 then the pipe size is 15
if Flow_rates > 0.2 and <= 1 then the pipe size is 22
if Flow_rates > 1 and <=1.9  then the pipe size is 32
if Flow_rates > 1.9 then the pipe size is 45
```

And for PVC I will use the follow logical operators:

```
if Flow_rates <= 0.1 then the pipe size is 15
if Flow_rates > 0.1 and <= 1 then the pipe size is 22
if Flow_rates > 1 and <=1.4  then the pipe size is 32
if Flow_rates > 1.4 then the pipe size is 45
```

And for Steel I will use the follow logical operators:

```
if Flow_rates <= 0.1 then the pipe size is 15
if Flow_rates > 0.1 and <= 0.8 then the pipe size is 22
if Flow_rates > 0.8 and <=1.5  then the pipe size is 32
if Flow_rates > 1.5 then the pipe size is 45
```

If I didn't have the list Material_pipes, it was easy to change the list Pipe_sizes. I could use the follow solution:

```
def flow_rate_to_size(rate):
    if rate <= 0.2:
        size = 15
    elif 0.2 < rate <= 1:
        size = 22
    elif 1 < rate <= 1.9:
        size = 32
    else:
        size = 45
    return size

Flow_rates = [0.1, 0.3, 1, 2, 0.4, 1.5]
Pipe_sizes = [Flow_rate_to_size(rate) for rate in Flow_rates]
print(Pipe_sizes)
```

But what can I do if `Pipe_sizes` depends also from the list `Material_pipes`?

Comment: why do the materials occur more than once?

Comment: They are different pipes...
Some of them are Copper, some are PVC and some are Steel.
So I need to check which material is it...

Thanks Pynchia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass in both pieces of information and use the appropriate one for the material passed in.  Going off of your example.

```
def flow_rate_to_size(rate, material):
    size = -1 # good to set an error state
    if material.lower() == 'copper':
        if rate <= 0.2:
            size = 15
        elif 0.2 < rate <= 1:
            size = 22
        elif 1 < rate <= 1.9:
            size = 32
        else:
            size = 45
    elif material.lower() == 'pvc':
        if rate <= 0.1:
            size = etc....
    etc...
    return size
```

Comment: thanks BlivetWidget...
I've tried to use your suggestion but it doesn't work....
Please have a look on what I did.
(scroll down the page please)

Thanks.

Comment: You accidentally left the material strings capitalized.  After material.lower(), you have to have an all-lower case string or it will always fail the test.  You don't have to use that method, but it helps to error proof it in case you ever write 'copper' or 'COPPER', etc.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```
from bisect import bisect

material_pipes = {'Copper': (0.2, 1.0, 1.9),
                  'PVC': (0.1, 1, 1.4),
                  'Steel': (0.1, 0.8, 1.5)}
pipe_sizes = [15,22,32,45]

def flow_rate_to_size(material, rate):
    pos = bisect(material_pipes[material], rate)
    return pipe_sizes[pos]
```

examples:

```
print(flow_rate_to_size('Copper', 0.0))
print(flow_rate_to_size('Copper', 1.4))
print(flow_rate_to_size('Copper', 2.5))
```

produces:

```
15
32
45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hi guys....

I don;t understand why but it doesn't work...

have a look please...

Pipe_sizes = [15,15,22,15,32,45]
Flow_rates = [0.1,0.3,1,2,0.4,1.5]
Material_pipes = ["Copper", "Copper", "PVC", "Steel", "Steel", "Copper"]

def Flow_rate_to_size(rate,material):
    size = -1 # good to set an error state
    if material.lower() == 'Copper':
        if rate <= 0.2:
            size = 15
        elif 0.2 < rate <= 1:
            size = 22
        elif 1 < rate <= 1.9:
            size = 32
        else:
            size = 45
    elif material.lower() == 'PVC':
        if rate <= 0.1:
            size = 15
        elif 0.1 < rate <= 1:
            size = 22
        elif 1 < rate <= 1.4:
            size = 32
        else:
            size = 45    
    elif material.lower() == 'Steel':
        if rate <= 0.1:
            size = 15
        elif 0.1 < rate <= 0.8:
            size = 22
        elif 0.8 < rate <= 1.5:
            size = 32
        else:
            size = 45    
    return size


Pipe_sizes = [Flow_rate_to_size(rate,material) for rate in Flow_rates]
print(Pipe_sizes)
```

Comment: For future reference, probably makes more sense to edit your original question.  Anyway, I left a comment on my answer explaining that the material strings should be typed out in lower case for those tests.